# PHP Form - Text Box or Dropdown List Required

Tags: php, html, drop-down-menu

I was wondering if someone can help me with this. I have a php contact form with two required fields. Either the user needs to fill out the text field, or select an option from a dropdown list. One or the either needs to be filled out.  Here is what I have:

```
    // previous requisition number
if(trim($_REQUEST['prevReqNum']) === '')  {
    $prevReqNumError = '<span class="error">Please enter your previous requisition number.</span>';
    $hasError = true;
} else if (!preg_match("/^([1]-)?[a-z0-9]{6}$/i", trim($_REQUEST['prevReqNum']))) {
    $prevReqNumError = '<span class="error">You entered an invalid requisition number.</span>';
    $hasError = true;

// assigned engineer
} else if(empty($_POST['engineer'])) {
$engineerError = '<span class="error">Please select the engineer that you were working with.</span>';
$hasError = true; }
else{
$engineer = $_POST['engineer'];
}
```

and here is the HTML:

```
         <p><label for="prevReqNum">*Previous Requisition Number:&nbsp;</label><input type="text" size="40" name="prevReqNum" id="prevReqNum" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['prevReqNum'])) echo $_POST['prevReqNum'];?>" placeholder=" eg. 000000" /> <?php if($prevReqNumError != '') { ?><span class="error"><?=$prevReqNumError;?></span><?php } ?>
             or <label for="engineer">Assigned Engineer: </label><select name='engineer' id="engineer" size="1">
              <option value="" selected="selected">Select</option>
              <option <?php echo $engineer=='Dexter'?'selected':''; ?> >Dexter</option>
              <option <?php echo $engineer=='Jake'?'selected':''; ?> >Jake</option>
              <option <?php echo $engineer=='Mo'?'selected':''; ?> >Mo</option>
              <option <?php echo $engineer=='Richard'?'selected':''; ?> >Richard</option>
            </select> <?php if($engineerError != '') { ?><span class="error"><?=$engineerError;?></span><?php } ?></p>
```

So either the user should fill out the requisition number, or choose the engineer they were working with.  I got the requisition number text field working. So when I leave that blank I get an error message. But when I leave the engineer dropdown menu  unselected, I get no error message. Please forgive me I'm not a programmer, so I'm not sure what's wrong here.  Thank you!

Comment: The HTML is inside the <form></form> tags, but the above PHP is inside the <?php   ?> tags.  They are inside the same php page but separated.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add this to your PHP.  It looks like you just need to check for an engineer and a prevReqNum and if neither of them exist, return an error message.  This is just following the other validations.

```
if (empty($_POST['engineer']) && trim($_REQUEST['prevReqNum']) === '') {
    $prevReqNumError = '<span class="error">Please choose an engineer or enter a requisition number.</span>';
    $hasError = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below will sort out the potential errors. Either both are empty or not.

```
<?php
$reqNumber=trim($_POST['prevReqNum']);
$engineer=$_POST['engineer'];
if(empty($reqNumber) && empty($engineer)){
$prevReqNumError = '<span class="error">Please enter your previous requisition number or select an engineer.</span>';
$hasError = true;
}
else{
if(!empty($reqNumber))  {
if (!preg_match("/^([1]-)?[a-z0-9]{6}$/i", $reqNumber)) {
$prevReqNumError = '<span class="error">You entered an invalid requisition number.</span>';
$hasError = true;
}
else{
  if(empty($_POST['engineer'])){
    $engineerError = '<span class="error">Please select the engineer that you were working with.</span>';
    $hasError = true;
  }  
  }
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is the layout of the logic.  Look carefully, you have:

```
if
else if
else if
else
```

Once PHP has matched the "if", the other tests are skipped.

You want if/else for previous request number, and another if/else for assigned engineer, because if either is wrong, you want to throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

I Tried To Help. It Will Help.

```
Add Form "action" and "onsubmit" in <form></form> tag.

<form method="POST" action="Give Here" onsubmit="return CheckValidation()">
<p>
    <label for="prevReqNum">*Previous Requisition Number:&nbsp;</label>
    <input type="text" size="40" name="prevReqNum" id="prevReqNum" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['prevReqNum'])) echo $_POST['prevReqNum'];?>" placeholder=" eg. 000000" />
    <span class="error InvalidRegdNo" style="display:none;">You entered an invalid requisition number.</span>
    <span class="error EmptyRegdNo" style="display:none;">Please enter your previous requisition number.</span>             
    OR <label for="engineer">Assigned Engineer: </label>
    <select name='engineer' id="engineer" size="1">
        <option value="" selected="selected">Select</option>
        <option <?php echo $engineer=='Dexter'?'selected':''; ?> >Dexter</option>
        <option <?php echo $engineer=='Jake'?'selected':''; ?> >Jake</option>
        <option <?php echo $engineer=='Mo'?'selected':''; ?> >Mo</option>
        <option <?php echo $engineer=='Richard'?'selected':''; ?> >Richard</option>
    </select>
    <span class="error SelectEngineer" style="display:none;">Please select the engineer that you were working with.</span>
    <span class="error SelectAtleastOne" style="display:none;">Please select atleast engineer or type registration no.</span>
</p>

</form>

<script>
    function CheckValidation()
    {
        var RegNo=$('#prevReqNum').val();
        var Engineer=$('#engineer').val();

        /*First Check Valid Registration Number*/
        if (!preg_match("/^([1]-)?[a-z0-9]{6}$/i", trim(RegNo)))
        {
            $('.InvalidRegdNo').show();
            return false;
        }
        if(RegNo=="" && Engineer=="")
        {
            $('.SelectAtleastOne').show();
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you all for your help and response! You've been very helpful! :-)